# How to match Service Worker pattern?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I would like to add a cache rule to the service worker that works on the URLs that contain alphanumeric characters with more than a hyphen. Here’s what I would like to do:

```
// will match
/one-word/
/one-two-words/

// will not match if no hyphen or more than two slash
/oneword/
/word/oneword/
```

And that’s what my current code looks like which is matching almost all the URLs:

```
registerRoute.url.pathname.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9-a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}/gi)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: `if (registerRoute.url.pathname.split('-').length > 1)`

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9-a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}` doesn't make sense. Did you mean `[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}`?